# ActiveRecord Multi-association query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I've got three models:

- User
- User Interest
- Interest Tags

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_interests 
end
```

InterestTag Model

```
class InterestTag < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :user_interests, :dependent => :destroy

validates :name, :uniqueness => true

end
```

UserInterest Model

```
class UserInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :interest_tag
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'd like to use ActiveRecord to include the name of the user's interests when loading their profile using the following query:

`@user = User.find(current_user.id, :include => [{:user_interests => :interest_tags}])`

Migrations for interest_tags + user_interests

```
create_table :interest_tags do |t|
  t.string :name, :null => false, :size => 30
  t.timestamp :created_at
end

create_table :user_interests do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :interest_tag_id
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have solve by performing: @user = User.find(current_user.id, :include => {:user_interests => :interest_tag})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an `has_many :through` association on `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_interests 
  has_many :interest_tags, :through => :user_interests
end

class UserInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :interest_tag
  belongs_to :user
end

class InterestTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_interests, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Now you can eager load the tags as follows:

```
User.find(current_user.id, :include => :interest_tags)
```

**Note:**

You might want to look at the [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building a tagging system, like in stackoverflow: every user kann have multiple tags that they are interested in. In that case the user_interests table is only a join table and does not need a model. Just use [has_and_belong_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) on the two real models.

See also [this article](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html) on different ways to implement tagging with more or less normalized relational databases. You could also use a non-relational database like Mongodb, there you would need only one table to do tagging, see [the cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/).